# ng-file-upload not sending file size in Content-Disposition to ASP.NET Web Api 2

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, asp.net-web-api, directive

I am using danialfarid/ng-file-upload to upload files in AngularJS to Web Api 2.

I am trying to validate `fileSize` server side. ASP.NET Web Api has

```
headers.ContentDisposition.Size
```

but ng-file-upload is not sending size. It sends:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="foo.jpg"
```

How do I make ng-file-upload send the size of the file it is uploading so I can validate it in ASP.NET Web Api?

```
$upload.upload({
    url: url,
    method: 'PUT',
    file: file
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?